# Converting Android post request to iOS swift using NSURLSession

Tags: android, ios, swift, http, post

I'm trying to convert my Android post request to iOS (Swift). Currently, this is the Android code:

```
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
    json.put("major", Major);
    json.put("minor", Minor);
    json.put("uuid", UUID);
    json.put("userid", id);

    int TIMEOUT_MILLISEC = 10000;  // = 10 seconds

    HttpParams httpParams = new BasicHttpParams();
    HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParams, TIMEOUT_MILLISEC);
    HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParams, TIMEOUT_MILLISEC);
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParams);

    HttpPost request = new HttpPost("http://" + ipAddress + ":8080/");
    request.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");


    request.setEntity(new ByteArrayEntity(
                json.toString().getBytes("UTF8")));
    HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
```

This works perfectly fine.
However, when I try to convert it to Swift, the server doesn't receive anything even though I know that it's executing the request.

Swift:

```
            var request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: URLString)!)
            var session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
            request.HTTPMethod = "POST"

            var params = ["major": "1", "minor": "2", "uuid": "00000000-1111-2222-3333-444444444444", "userid": "3"] as Dictionary<String, String>


            request.HTTPBody = try! NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(params, options: [])

            request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
            let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request) { data, response, error in
                guard data != nil else {
                    print("no data found: \(error)")
                    return
                }

                do {
                    if let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: []) as? NSDictionary {
                        let success = json["success"] as? Int                                  
                    } else {
                        let jsonStr = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)    
                    }
                } catch let parseError {
                    let jsonStr = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
                }
            }
```

Any help or direction would be nice. Thanks.

Edit 1: A task.resume() got me a response from the server. However, if anyone knows how to convert "request.setEntity(new ByteArrayEntity(json.toString().getBytes("UTF8")));" in Swift, that would be really helpful.

Comment: Does your response closure is called ?

Comment: task.resume() was the solution, thanks for the help. Response closure didn't get called initially.

Comment: The task.resume() executed the request, but I was wondering how to express "    request.setEntity(new ByteArrayEntity(
                json.toString().getBytes("UTF8")));" in Swift.

Comment: OK, I see. You used this to post request in Android, but you have the relative code already in your swift code to set the HttpBody.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you forget to add `task.resume` ?

Comment: Well. they other guy just copied my answer :o. I'm faster man.. check the time.

Comment: I mean technically he was right with the task.resume() but yeah you were right. Do you know how to express "request.setEntity(new ByteArrayEntity(
                json.toString().getBytes("UTF8")));" in Swift?

Comment: This process is the serialization? NSJsonSerialization.objectWithData() is doing the UTF8 decoding, either to array or dictionary

Comment: OK, I see. You used this to post request in Android, but you have the relative code already in your swift code to set the HttpBody.

Answer (score 1):

@Naga Krishnamraju
For your second concern where need to parse json string to object you can do that using following way

```
      if(response != nil)
            {
                // Print out reponse body
                let responseString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
                //print("****** response data = \(responseString!)")

                do {
                    let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: []) as? NSDictionary

                    print(json ?? "Error")
                    print("responseString :-%@",responseString ?? "error");
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {

                        if((json?.count)! > 0)
                        {
                           //here you get json as dictionary now you can have your implementation
                        }

                    }

                }catch
                {
                    print(error)
                    failure(error as NSError);

                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

`task.resume()` after block will do the job